# change design table position

Tags: flutter, dart

I've try to change table `add row list` from `Design A` to `Design B` but it give some error. I don't know how to make it work. Hope there are some one here can give me some idea how to solve this issue...

Note: `Design B` only need 1 serial number per group..

**

> **Design A**

**
[image]

> **Design B**

[image]

And this code `Design A`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = MediaQuery.of(context);

    return Container(

        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey[300])),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            top: 15,
        ),
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                    Text(widget.itemDetails.configDetail,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Container(
                        // delete button
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            color: Colors.red[400]),
                        width: data.size.width * 0.125,
                        height: data.size.width * 0.035,
                        child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                                widget.deleteButtonClicked();
                            },
                            child: Text('Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: data.size.width * 0.020))),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            Container(
                width: data.size.width,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Table(
                        defaultColumnWidth:
                        FixedColumnWidth(data.size.width * 0.145),
                        border:
                        TableBorder.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey[500]),
                        children: [
                            TableRow(children: [
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                        "Serial Number",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                        "A",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                        "B",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                        "C",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                        "D",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    )),
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                    child: Text(
                                        "Action",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                    )),
                            ]),
                            ...this.rowList.map((row) {
                                return TableRow(children: [
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            initialValue: row['serialNo'],
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                                row['serialNo'] = value;
                                                updateDetails();
                                            },
                                            cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                isDense: true,
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                                            ),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))),
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            initialValue: row['first'],
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                                row['first'] = value;
                                                updateDetails();
                                            },
                                            cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                isDense: true,
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                                            ),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))),
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            initialValue: row['second'],
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                                row['second'] = value;
                                                updateDetails();
                                            },
                                            cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                isDense: true,
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                                            ),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))),
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            initialValue: row['third'],
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                                row['third'] = value;
                                                updateDetails();
                                            },
                                            cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                isDense: true,
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                                            ),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))),
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            initialValue: row['fourth'],
                                            onChanged: (value) {
                                                row['fourth'] = value;
                                                updateDetails();
                                            },
                                            cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                isDense: true,
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
                                            ),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))),
                                    Container(
                                        // add button
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[500])),
                                        height: data.size.width * 0.05,
                                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 16.0),
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                    rowList.remove(row);
                                                    updateDetails();
                                                });
                                            },
                                        ),
                                    )
                                ]);
                            }).toList()
                        ]))),
            Container(
                // add button
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[500], width: 1.5)),
                height: data.size.width * 0.039,
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {

                        setState(() {
                            Map < String, String > rowValue = Map < String, String > ();
                            rowValue['serialNo'] = '';
                            rowValue['first'] = '';
                            rowValue['second'] = '';
                            rowValue['third'] = '';
                            rowValue['fourth'] = '';

                            print(rowValue.length);
                            this.rowList.add(rowValue);
                            updateDetails();
                        });
                    },
                    child: Text('+ Add Box',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey[900],
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: data.size.width * 0.019))),
            ),
        ]));
}
```

Hopefully.., can help

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: _"I've try to change table add row list from Design A to Design B but it give some error."_  What error?

Comment: this error.. 
`Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#3071c relayoutBoundary=up44
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
       ⣟
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/table.dart': Failed assertion: line
1185 pos 12: '_rowTops.length == rows + 1': is not true.`